# Can an answer be undeleted?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-answers

I was stupid an [answered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/184624/37138) a question with just a link.  I then went back and edited my answer to actually something useful, only to find that no one will ever see it again because a moderator deleted it (Sad Panda).  Is there a way to get it undeleted?

Comment: [Rachel's answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5481/25936) is the correct one, all you need to do is flag for moderation attention. Not necessary now, I've undeleted your answer, thanks for taking the time to expand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your post has been edited to fix the reason it was deleted, then you can flag it for a moderator to undelete with the "flag" link below the post. Just select the "Other" option, and state the reason for your flag (that it was edited to no longer be a link-only answer, and that you want it undeleted)

Users with over 10k reputation can see deleted posts and vote to undelete them, however we can only vote to delete posts that were deleted by the community. Posts deleted by a moderator need to be undeleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 2):

Deleted answers are visible to users with a reputation over 10,000. It can be undeleted if necessary (ask an admin). But usually if it was deleted, there was generally a reason for it.

Comment: Small clarification: Deleted answers are visible to their authors, regardless of rep, provided the question itself isn't deleted.